# JSON string to byte[] JSONParseException

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, entity, lob

I've gotten a whole bunch of angularJS, rest and entity stuff working together to be able to save form data via REST in my POSTGRES DB.

However, I decided to try something different with one of the entity fields so that I can store longer bits of text in the DB. I wanted to use an Entity with a field as follows:

```
   @Column
   private int age;

   @Lob
   @Column(length = 2147483647)
   private byte[] otherNeeds;
```

Now the entity was created just fine. I built my REST interface on top of that based from JBoss Forge scaffolding. Everything works fine with my saving of the form via REST as long as I keep the "otherNeeds" field empty.

Here's my form:

```
    <input id="age" type="number" ng-model="primaryGuest.age"></input>

    <input id="otherNeeds" type="text" ng-maxlength="2147483647" ng-model="primaryGuest.otherNeeds"></input>
```

All this data is passed through correctly into my JavaScript objects in AngularJS, and when I click the save() button, I can see the POST request go thru to my REST interface with the following payload:

```
    {
    otherNeeds: "jjjjjj"
    age: "10"
    }
```

However, the response back from the server is an exception:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character '"' (code 0x22) in base64 content
at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@1a37992c; line: 1, column: 67]
at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433) [jackson-core-asl-1.9.9-redhat-2.jar:1.9.9-redhat-2]
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.getBinaryValue(Utf8StreamParser.java:402) [jackson-core-asl-1.9.9-redhat-2.jar:1.9.9-redhat-2]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.PrimitiveArrayDeserializers$ByteDeser.deserialize(PrimitiveArrayDeserializers.java:289)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.PrimitiveArrayDeserializers$ByteDeser.deserialize(PrimitiveArrayDeserializers.java:275)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2704)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1315)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:63) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:169) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
... 33 more
```

So, I'm not sure how to handle this scenario to have my object be transformed into something that would be acceptable for the byte[] format. I have the option of going back to a standard "String" field but I want to be able to provide the user with an "unlimited" amount of text that they can provide.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the issue was with the @Lob type column and why it didn't want to push the data into the DB; however, eventually, I changed from

```
@Lob
```

to

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringClobType")
private String otherNeeds;
```

And then I was able to manage this more straightforwardly and push content into the DB via the REST calls.

Answer (score 0):

When the property type is byte[] and the response is in String jackson thinks the data is base64 encoded and tries to decode it and convert it to byte[]. But when you changed the type to String no such conversion is taking place and the string is directly saved in database.